# how to write data model properly with nested types properly or use CoreData in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, struct, data-modeling

```
struct Bag {
   let name: String
   let wallets:[Wallet]

   mutating func addWallet(wallet: Wallet){
      wallets.append(wallet) 
   }
}

struct Wallet {
   let name: String
   let cards:[Card]

   mutating func addCard(card: card){
      cards.append(card) 
   }

}

struct Card {
   let name: String
   let number: String
}

class Manager{
   // it can add , remove and keep track of Bags
}
```

I am learning about creating my own data model.

This is a simplified version of my App's data model, where many wallets can be put in a Bag, and many credit cards can be put in a wallet.

Question 1. I have a Manager Class to add, remove and get stuff from my Bag, Should I have 2 more classes to do the same thing for my Wallet and Card struct ? Or have mutating function inside struct..and maybe added in a getFunction inside those structs

Question 2. Is there a better way to model this, it seems like a big mess.

Question 3. In my previous Apps I would just have 3 simple structs and have relationships in coreData and just let CoreData handles everything. can CoreData be used to built a data Model or it need to be separated ?

What is the best way to do this so that is more readable
and is easier to be understood and maintain in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just simplify all of the structs to make the parts you want to modify vars, you have to do that anyway for the mutating methods to work - but dump the mutating methods:

```
struct Bag {
    let name: String
    var wallets:[Wallet]
}

struct Wallet {
    let name: String
    var cards:[Card]
}

struct Card {
    let name: String
    let number: String
}
```

Then, why even have a Manager class for anything?  The structure of what is possible is already defined by the structs, and to add a new card to a wallet is already very simple:

```
myWallet1.cards.append(myCard2)
```

I'm not quite sure what you were trying to ask with question 3 - I think you were trying to ask if you can use CoreData to define a data model that you can use without a database?  You can't create managed objects without a context/persistent store coordinator.  You can have a core data model that is all in memory.  That's probably better asked as a separate question.